# Creating a table with an age constraint based on a date_of_birth attribute with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    date_of_birth           date            NOT NULL
    );
```

Trying to make it so that someone cannot enter an age less than 18 when inserting values into the table. How would I do this with the date_of_birth attribute?

Note: I do know how to use the CHECK(age > 18), but I don't know how to incorporate this with the date_of_birth attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a CHECK constraint based on the value of current_date. Since current_date always increases over time, any value that passes this constraint today will also pass it tomorrow.

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  date_of_birth date NOT NULL
    check ( date_of_birth < (current_date - interval '18' year ) )
);

insert into customer values ('1996-09-29');
```

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "customer" violates check constraint "customer_date_of_birth_check"
```

```
insert into customer values ('1996-09-28');
```

```
Query returned successfully: one row affected, 22 ms execution time.
```

Comment: Alternatively: `check ( age(date_of_birth) >= interval '18' year)`

Comment: This approach is very elegant. I could also suggest something like: 
`CHECK (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - "date_of_birth" >= INTERVAL '18 years');` @a_horse_with_no_name